# Is it possible to run scripts on django using only ftp?

Tags: python, mysql, django, ftp

I am newbie to python and django, but this time I need a fast solution. I've got a problems, using hosting where my django application is deployed so I need to migrate to another server, but I have no ssh or telnet to server, only ftp connection for this server. I need to export data from django database. I wanted to write a script and put it somewhere in django application for data export, but when I put my modification on server behavior does not change(as nothing changed). Also when I remove .pyc files from djagno (for example. views.pyc) - no changes, and when I remove .py file - nothings changes (for example views.py).
As far as I read about django, it is possible that server is running with option "-noreload". 
So question is it any possible way to dump database only via ftp and django/python?
(remote connection via mysql is disabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ftp stands for "file transfer protocol", not for "remote shell", so *no*, you cannot use ftp to execute a command / program / script / whatever. But why don't you just ask your hosting how to get a dump of your data ?

Comment: ok. So it is the only one solution. I just wanted a verification.